# Python custom ArgParse is not recognizing any argument

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am creating a custom arg parser to instantiate it in my main program.

Here is the class:

```
class CustomArguments:
    def __init__(self):
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Possible command line arguments")
        #this is a required argument
        parser.add_argument("locations_file", help="POI file location", type=str)
        #also required
        parser.add_argument("users_file", help="User file location", type=str)
        parser.add_argument("--split", "-s" ,
                            help="Split threshold. File will be split if records exceed this amount",
                            type=int, required=False, default=100000)
        parser.add_argument("--batch_size", "-b" , help="Size for each split of the file.",
                            type=int, required=False, default=100000)
        parser.add_argument("--max_threads", "-t",  help="Max amount of threads for the thread pool",
                            type=int, required=False, default=10)
        arguments = parser.parse_args()
```

main file is just

```
app_args = CustomArguments()
poi_file = os.path.join(app_args.locations_file)
foo
```

The problem is that when I run the program (with every argument supplied), I get the error `'CustomArguments' object has no attribute 'locations_file'`
I also tried to call `parse_args()` from main like `app_args.parser.parse_args` or even just through `app_args.arguments` but it says that neither of those 2 attributes exist in `app_args`

Comment: Could you try with just a function (without the class) returning the `arguments` ?

Comment: The parsing results are in the `arguments` variable, which is local to the `init`.  It needs to be assigned to `self.arguments` or something like that.

Comment: the problem is with thw class code, not argparse.  But it may help to experiment more with a simple use of argparse to understand just what it does (or does not do)